# Shopify - Loading data from an External REST API in a Liquid template

Tags: json, wordpress, rest, shopify

I need to load some data (A WordPress Menu) from an external REST API into my Shopify template. I'm assuming I need to use an App proxy to do this. I've looked through the documentation but I'm a little confused as to how to go about this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I often use jquery with an ajax call to an api end point that either

1. sends me back formatted html
2. send me back json data that I parse and form the html via javascript.

```
    
        jQuery(window).load(function(){
            data = {};
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'https://yourapp.herokuapp.com/yourendpoint.json',
                    data: data,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) { 
                        console.log(data);
                        $.each( data, function(i, item) {
                             console.log(item);
                            // do something with your data here
                        });
                    }
                });
        });
```

Comment: Yes this is pretty much exactly what I ended up going with. It's working well. It turns out that the Shopify App Proxy won't work for what I was trying to do anyway. Thanks.

Comment: Hey guys! Trying to use Ajax but blocked by access control of course, is there any simple way to make a request to an external API?? I looked into making a Shopify app but it seems like overkill for one request.